# How to url encode in Django views

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, url

In Django, I want to do this

```
 <a href="{% url 'firstapp:create' %}?next={{ nextos|urlencode }}">
```

but in my views.py, when I render a page

```
return render(request, 'create' + parameter next=nextos)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just had to do this myself.  Ended up with this solution

```
from django.utils.http import urlencode
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
```

Then in your view:

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect( reverse('firstapp:create') + '?' + urlencode({'next': nextos }))
```

I hope that helps!
Nick

Answer (score 2):

A slight variation on the accepted answer: python's f-string notation is quite readable here:

```
HttpResponseRedirect( f"{reverse('firstapp:create')}?{urlencode({'next': nextos })}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
 <a href="{% url 'firstapp:create' next=nextos %}">
```

This generates the URL without the need of encoding.

Comment: I want to tell Django that but in the views.py module, instead of in a template. As I don't have template tags in views.py, I am needing a way to code this `return render(request, 'create' + parameter next=nextos)`

Comment: in view.py you can use `redirect(to, *args, permanent=False, **kwargs)` or `reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, current_app=None)`. you can do like this `reverse('create', kwargs={'next': nextos})`

Comment: When using redirect without kwargs, it works, but when adding the kwargs I get `NoReverseMatch at /lop.html
Reverse for 'create' with keyword arguments '{'kwargs': {'next': '/tpn'}}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['create\\.html$']`

Comment: Do I have to code in urls.py something like this? `path(r'logino/(?P<next>.)/$', views.loginohtml, name='logino'),`  Instead of something like this? `path('logino.html', views.loginohtml, name='logino'),`

Comment: my latest try gave this error  `Reverse for 'logino' with keyword arguments '{'next': '/tpn'}' not found. 3 pattern(s) tried: ['createa/\\(\\?P(?P<next>[^/]+)\\\\d\\+\\)/\\$$', 'logino/\\(\\?P(?P<next>[^/]+)\\\\d\\+\\)/\\$$', 'logino\\.html$']`

Comment: finally made it with : `return HttpResponseRedirect("{}?next={}".format(reverse('firstapp:logino'), esteticas))`